# Laravel/Eloquent ver si dos o más modelos tienen la misma relación

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Tengo los modelos: `Partido` y `Coalicion`. Sabemos que una coalición está conformada por varios `Partido` y un `Partido` puede pertenecer a diferentes `Coalicion` (Many to Many).

Modelo:

```
class Coalicion extends Model
{
    public function partidos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Partido::class);
    }
}
```

Desde la vista envié varios id de `Coalicion` para poderlos buscar y trabajar con ellos.

```
...
public function example(Request $request)
    {
        $coaliciones = $request->coaliciones;
        foreach ($coaliciones as $c) {
            $coalicion = Coalicion::find($c);
            # Aqui buscamos por ID uno a uno las coaliciones
            dump($c->partidos);
            # Y mostramos los partidos relacionados.
        }
    }
```

Al hacer `dump()` el navegador me da lo siguiente (por ejemplo solicité solamente 2 `Coalicion`):

```
Collection {#1 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Partido {#271 ▶} #Aquí está el partido con ID 1
    1 => Partido {#268 ▶}
  ]
}
Collection {#2 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Partido {#279 ▶}
    1 => Partido {#280 ▶}
    2 => Partido {#283 ▶} #Aquí está el partido con ID 1
  ]
}
```

En lo anterior existe un partido repetido pero para unas elecciones no puede existir el mismo partido en distintas coaliciones, sin embargo me interesa dejar las coaliciones previamente existentes para reutilizarlas en un futuro

Comment: Tu tabla de rompimiento <partido/coalición> debe ser un histórico supongo.  Se que Laravel tiene `attach`, `detach`, `sync` y `toggle` para manejar las relaciones mtm, pero fuera de eso, no se me ocurre otra forma mas que hacerlo manual. Las funciones están en [esta seccion de la documentacion.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models). Tambien puedes ver funciones para comparar arreglos de php como [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php) o [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect.php)

Comment: Si los modelos son collections (no estoy seguro), puedes usar también https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-diff

Comment: A mí la verdad no me queda claro lo que se pretende hacer en la pregunta, es simplemente verificar si Inn partido está repetido en una consulta de coaliciones?

Comment: Sí, saber si está repetido justamente el partido en diferentes coaliciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una forma pero no se si sea la correcta o mejor forma de hacer esto.
En el modelo `Coalicion` creé la siguiente función:

```
public function partidosId()
    {
        return $this->partidos->pluck('id');
    }
```

De esa forma obtengo solamente los `id` de la tabla `partidos`, posteriormente en el controlador creo un `array` vacío y en el agrego todos los `id` iterando con `foreach`, después y por último verifico si los valores únicos del array que contiene ahora todos los `id` es menor que el conteo de los valores (deben ser iguales ya que todos deben ser únicos), lo muestro en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public function example(Request $request)
    {
        $coaliciones = $request->coaliciones;
        $allItems = [];
        foreach ($coaliciones as $c) {
            $coalicion = Coalicion::find($c);
            $allItems = array_merge($allItems, $coalicion->partidosId()->toArray());
        }
        if (count(array_unique($allItems))<count($allItems)) {
            dd("Repetidos");
        }else{
            dd("Únicos");
        }
    }
```

Si encuentran una mejor forma indíquenmelo por favor.